# Grails: use list in Controller and View

Tags: grails, groovy, criteria, gsp, join

```
class Candidate  {
    String username;
    static HasMany=[applications:Application]
}

class Vote {
   String name;
   Date firstdate;
   Date enddate ;
   static HAsMany=[applications:Application]
}



  class Application {
        Date datedemand;
        Candidate candidate; 
        Vote vote;
   static belongsTo = [candidate:Candidate,vote:Vote]
    }
```

I want to display the list of votes and if I click on a vote, it displays the list of candidates for this vote.
I started ​​the following attempt, and I remain blocked :

```
def candidatsGrpByVte(){
    def results = Application.withCriteria {
    createAlias("vote", "vote")
        projections {
            groupProperty("vote.name") 
        }
    }
}

    def candidatesByVName(def vname){
        def results= Application.createCriteria().list() {
            createAlias("candidate","candidatAlias")
            createAlias("vote","voteAlias")
            eq('voteAlias.name',vname)
            projections {
               property('candidatAlias.username')
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

I want to see the candidates in a vote from Application.
how I displayed in a view.
can you give me an idea ?

Comment: One Application hasMany candidate and hasOne candidate at the same time?

Comment: Get rid of your java accent by removing those semicolons!

Comment: + Why don't you use plurals for `hasMany`?

Answer (score 0):

The mappings look complex than it should be. `Vote` is not directly related to `Candidate` and you want to list candidates per vote.

The only way `Vote` is related to `Candidate` is through `Application`. So you have to grab the `Application` for a `Vote` and show all the `Candidate`s for the `Application`.

```
//Lazily:-
def voteCandidature = [:]
Vote.list()?.each{vote->
    voteCandidature << [(vote.name) : vote.application?.candidate?.asList()]
}

   //Eagerly:-
   def candidatesByVote(){
        def results = Application.createCriteria().list{
           vote{

           }
           candidate{

           }
        }
    }

    results.each{application->
       def votes = application.vote
       def candidates = application.candidate
       //Lost after this
       //You have bunch of votes and bunch of candidates
       //but both belong to the same application
    }
```

What does `Vote` signify actually? Can you elaborate on each of the domain classes use, mainly `Vote` and `Application`? And why don't you use plurals for `hasMany`?

Comment: Try the lazy path mentioned in the answer.

Comment: please I change the class domains. is it there's another proposal